# stuck in node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start

Tags: react-native

It is stuck when installing:

[image]

it can run two days ago,but now it can't, just be stuck

[image]

I don't know why,so I ask for help,thanks

Comment: Do you have enough space disk ? It could be the problem. Anyway try to re-install everything, and which OS did you use ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the past. I resolved it by uninstalling **watchman**:

```sh
brew uninstall watchman
```

After some time I installed **watchman** again and the problem did not occur.
But most probably it depends on **watchman** interface or a bug, so I recommend trying the following steps:

1. Update homebrew: `brew update`, `brew upgrade`
2. Reinstall **watchman**: `brew reinstall watchman`
3. Reset **watchman** caches: `watchman watch-del-all`
4. Shutdown **watchman**: `watchman shutdown-server` (it will be started automatically on `react-native start`)

For more commands see `watchman --help`